# Hyperbola's estimator

Tags: algebraic-geometry, estimation

I have a set of data. This set represents an approximation of a hyperbola.
Is there a good way to estimate a rectangular hyperbola's function from this set?

Comment: I suggest ot add the definition of a homographic function, because not everyone is familiar with this notion.

Answer (score 0):

I can propose a non-formal approach.

We sort data with respect to $|x|$. After that, we try to exhibit the horisontal asymptote. Next, we do the same to find vertical asymptote by sorting with respect to $|y|$. After that we translate our set of data such that the asymptotes are the axes lines (i.e. we deal with $y=k/x$), then we multiply the $y$ component by $x$ component and try to estimate $k$.

I agree that exhibiting the asymptote might be tricky, especially if we don't have the data "far from origin".